# Delphi Indy10 IMAP Decoding MIME attachment

Tags: delphi, imap, indy10

Using Delphi 11.

After downloading an email using `TIdIMAP4`, scanning through the `MessageParts`, how do I detect if a `MessagePart` contains a MIME encoded attachment, and how do I decode this into the original format (Image, documents, etc)?

```
procedure TImapForm.ProcessEmail(MSG: TIdMessage); 
begin
  ContainsAttachement := false;
    
  if Msg.MessageParts.Count > 0 then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Pred(Msg.MessageParts.Count) do
    begin
      if Msg.MessageParts.Items[i] is TIdText then
      begin
        // Process Text-only message here (Don't want HTML)
      end else
      begin
        ContainsAttachement := true;

        // if Msg.MessageParts[i].MessageParts.Encoding = meMIME then
        if MSG.ContentTransferEncoding = 'base64' then //??
        if Msg.MessageParts.Items[i].IsEncoded then //??
        begin
          // How to actually decode the MessagePart to a binary file?
        end;

      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Email example:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------wt6iyRLyQwO4w89MYm2jGb0w
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test

--------------wt6iyRLyQwO4w89MYm2jGb0w
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="Bart.jpg"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Bart.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4ThFRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAA4BAgAgAAAAngAAAA8B
AgAUAAAAvgAAABABAgAHAAAA1gAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAABoBBQABAAAA7gAAABsBBQABAAAA
9gAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAIAAAA/gAAADIBAgAUAAAAHgEAABMCAwABAAAAAgAAAGmH
etc.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TIdMessage` already handles this for you.  Look for `TIdAttachment` message parts, eg:

```
procedure TImapForm.ProcessEmail(MSG: TIdMessage); 
var
  MsgPart: TIdMessagePart;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ContainsAttachement := false;
    
  for i := 0 to Pred(Msg.MessageParts.Count) do
  begin
    MsgPart := Msg.MessageParts[i];

    if MsgPart is TIdText then
    //or: if MsgPart.PartType = mcptText then
    begin
      ...
    end
    else if MsgPart is TIdAttachment then
    //or: if MsgPart.PartType = mcptAttachment then
    begin
      ContainsAttachement := true;
      TIdAttachment(MsgPart).SaveToFile(...);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, MIME-encoded emails can have *complex* structures (see [HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/) on Indy's blog, for example).  Because of this, message parts can be nested, and have relationships with other message parts.  So, the *correct* way to process standalone attachments (as opposed to HTML-embedded images/media, for instance) in a MIME email is to loop *backwards* from last part to first part (because MIME parts are ordered from least complex to most complex) looking for attachments whose `ParentPart` property is `-1` (ie, a top-level part).

In general, if you find a message part whose `ContentType` property is `multipart/...` (like `multipart/related`) that interests you, then you can dig into its nested content by looping again looking for message parts whose `ParentPart` property refers to that message part that interested you.  And so on, and so on, as deep as you need to go.

For example:

```
procedure TImapForm.ProcessEmail(MSG: TIdMessage); 
var
  MsgPart: TIdMessagePart;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ContainsAttachement := false;
    
  if Msg.MessageParts.Count = 0 then
  begin
    if IsHeaderMediaType(Msg.ContentType, 'text/plain') then
    begin
      // Process Msg.Body here ...
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    for i := Pred(Msg.MessageParts.Count) downto 0 do
    begin
      MsgPart := Msg.MessageParts[i];

      if MsgPart.ParentPart = -1 then
      begin
        if MsgPart is TIdAttachment then
        begin
          ContainsAttachement := true;
          TIdAttachment(MsgPart).SaveToFile(...);
        end

        else if MsgPart is TIdText then
        begin
          if IsHeaderMediaType(MsgPart.ContentType, 'multipart') then
          begin
            // process nested parts whose ParentPart is MsgPart.Index ... 
          end

          else if IsHeaderMediaType(MsgPart.ContentType, 'text/plain') then
          begin
            // Process TIdText(MsgPart).Body here ...
          end;
        end;
      end;

    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That looks good and I will try it, but part of the MIME attachment contains the name of the file, which in turn of course indicate *what* type of file it is. If I call TIdAttachment(MsgPart).SaveToFile(...); where do I locate the filename?

Comment: @BartKindt `TIdMessagePart` has public `Name` (from the `Content-Type` header) and `FileName` (from the `Content-Disposition` or `Content-Type` header, depending on which is present) properties. The *type* of the file is specified in the `ContentType` property. Note that an attachment is not required to have a filename, and the presence of a filename does not imply the part is an attachment.